# Prediction for string in linear regression in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have a dataset like with three columns Type/Name/Price and want to predict the price based on Type and name.
Here Type/Name are categorical string values. And Price is numeric target variable.

My dataset looks like:

```
Type Name Price
A    ec1  1.5
B    ec2  2
A    ec2  3
C    ec1  1
B    ec3  1
```

I have to create a model for this dataset and want to predict for type/name.
What is the predicted price for Type - A and Name ec2?
Could you please provide the sample code.

Also, the dataset wont have fixed number of columns. Only the target variable is fixed as Price. Independent variables might have Type/Name/Date..etc fields.

Comment: Have you considered categorize those variables into a homogeneous type? For example:

A - ec1 --> Type_I
A - ec2 --> Type_II

B - ec1 --> Type_III

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary vectorizer on your input data. It will transform your categorical features into binary features of a vector.

Read more about it here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer

If I take your dataset as a example, it will look something like that:

```
data = [{"type": A, "name": ec1},
        {"type": B, "name": ec2},
        {"type": A, "name": ec2},
        {"type": C, "name": ec1},
        {"type": B, "name": ec3}]

from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

vectorizer = DictVectorizer()
vector_data = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
```

Now your `vector_data` is ready to be used in a Machine Learning model.

Comment: The solution usually goes to categorize those variables into a homogeneous type. For example:

A - ec1 --> Type_I
A - ec2 --> Type_II
B - ec1 --> Type_III
And so on. So you transform your problem into a single classification model.

Answer (score 1):

I convert the string values to numeric to fit linear model

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
import StringIO
data ='''Type,Name,Price
A,ec1,1.5
B,ec2,2
A,ec2,3
C,ec1,1
B,ec3,1'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(data))
mapping = {}
cols = df.drop('Price', axis=1).columns
for col in cols:
  mapping[col] = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(df[col].unique())}
def mapping_func(row):
  return pd.Series([mapping[col][row[col]] for col in cols])

X = df.apply(mapping_func, axis=1)
y = df['Price']
model = LinearRegression()

model.fit(X, y)
print model.predict([ mapping['Type']['B'], mapping['Name']['ec2']] )
```

output:

```
[ 1.57692308]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. If i don't know the number of independent variables i get like Type/Name are predefined in the code. But need logic where i get the no. of independent variables dynamically and have to handle inside the code. Can we do something like this?

Comment: @SyamalaReddy updated. the code should iter all the columns except "price"

Comment: Also, if i have a date column in those independent variables, can you tell me how to handle it please.

Comment: @SyamalaReddy you may convert the datetime to timestamp

Comment: Once i convert my date variable to timestamp, should i merge with X again and then pass to model? Sample dataset :                                
Type Name Price  Date
A    ec1  1.5 10/01/2017
B    ec2  2   10/01/2017
A    ec2  3   10/02/2017
C    ec1  1   10/03/2017
B    ec3  1   10/02/2017

Comment: And one more Q, My actual problem statement is when i get any type as input, i need to predict the person who can do with least price. So, I went with Regression algorithm first to predict the price of all people(by looping your code for all mapping[Name] against one Mapping[type]) and then get the least price person. Can you confirm if this is correct approach or do i need to with any other algorithm?

Comment: @SyamalaReddy the code I have is simply convert string to numeric, if your  features are numeric you don't need to convert it.

Comment: So, if my feature is date, convert to timestamp and join with rest all string fields(which are converted to numeric) and pass to model.fit. is it correct? Also, please check my other question above.

Comment: @SyamalaReddy yes. for the last question, the code is looping all the columns except y, in this case is "Price", than use all features to fit linear regression model.

Comment: Sorry, i think i didn't put my question properly. My doubt is in the last statemnt, model.predict, you gave two variable values - "B" and "ec1". What if i only have one variable with me as"B". Then i need to create a testdata in a form with all distinct names and one type -"B". So, my testdata will look something like this with 3 rows: B ec1, B ec2, B ec3 . And i need to predict price for all these 3 rows. So, in this case, do i need to loop for every row with this line - model.predict? Or can i predict for all the rows at one time? Could you please let me know. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @SyamalaReddy for prediction, you have to give all the features to get result.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will try with the info provided.

Comment: @SyamalaReddy np

Comment: If i give input for predction as A and ec3, im still seeing some prediction value. But in the history data i dont have any combination of A and ec3. Shouldn't we get 0 in that case?

Comment: @SyamalaReddy prediction will base on the linear model fit result. for easy understand, let assume x, y are all 1d data. the fit will be a line to close all the training data. thus when you pass data to model(even the data not existing in training data), the model still could give you a predication.

Comment: Oh..ok, Got it. This comes under overfitting the model..correct? Is there a way to exclude such cases while predicting?

Comment: I was trying to predict the best person who has least predicted price. But the names of people who didn't even mapped to that type. As u mentioned, model still gives prediction for the data that doesn't exist , how to exclude all such cases? When I try for type B and name ec1, I'm expecting the output to be 0 so that I will be able to get the predictions for only the cases which has correct mapping in training data